# Adding item into an array with push function

Tags: javascript

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sTVd.png)

Can someone verify where I went wrong?

Comment: I added a semicolon after displaytodos(); and get the same error

Comment: Why are you using a variable named `todos` to define both the collection and a string?

Comment: rename `addTodos` parameter `todos` because it is overriding the global `todos`one.

Comment: function addTodos() {
todos.push("new todos");
displayTodos();
}

Comment: I could to that, but if I want to add into my array, it would name all of the new one "new todos"

Answer (score 2):

`addTodos` parameter `todos` will override the global `todos` so just rename it to something else. see below example

```js
var todos = ['1','2','3'];

function display() {
 console.log(todos)
}

function addTodos(todo) {
 todos.push(todo)
 display()
}

addTodos('4')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having with your code is, you created a global variable `var todos` and at the same time in your `addTodos` function you added an argument `todos`, the JavaScript is accessing your function argument not the global variable,

Now change the name of the global variable, to something like `var myTodos` to avoid conflicting

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah that make a lot of sense, thank you

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

todos is a string not an array where error is occurring.

`string` type doesn't have `push` method. Also, local todos is found first in the local scope so it masks the array version.

Comment: I create a var todos, that's I didn't use it as a string. If I would've put "todos", it would add the word "todos" into my array

Comment: You are using the same name `todos` for BOTH your variable AND for the argument to `addTodos()`.  So inside the function `addTodos()`, it will ONLY see the argument `todos` which is a string.  So it is trying to call `push` on a string, which doesn't exist.

Comment: In the line `function addTodos(todos)`, the local variable name is `todos`. Now local one is masking the global one. Variables are looked from inner scope to outer scopes. Since todos is found at the local one, it is considered string in which push is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you have realised, you are sending in an argument called todos. You are effectively overwriting the todos array that has been set previously. Replacing it with a new variable name would fix the problem

```
function addTodos(newTodo) {
  todos.push(newTodo);
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhh, thanks for the input